# computing complexity of kmeans algorithm

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I want to compute complexity of kmeans algorithm based on complexity theory.

I have already read the standard algorithm of kmeans from wikipedia: [Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering)

Comment: Did you make another account just to answer your own question?

Comment: No the two acconts belong to two different people, that's only a friend who saw the post and wanted to help but wasn't too helpful as you can see!

Answer (score 3):

Time complexity for K-means clustering is

```
(  ×  ×  ×  )
◦  = number of points,
◦  = number of clusters,
◦  = number of iterations,
◦  = number of attributes
```

The storage required is

```
(( + ))
◦  = number of points,
◦  = number of clusters,
◦  = number of attributes
```

Answer (score 0):

If (you haven't understood K-means)  http://home.deib.polimi.it/matteucc/Clustering/tutorial_html/kmeans.html

Else

Initialize means (e.g. by picking k samples at random)

• Iterate:  (I times)

(1) assign each point to nearest mean

(2) move “mean” to center of its cluster.

(3) finally, this algorithm aims at minimizing an objective function, in this case a squared error function. The objective function has complexity of kn as you see it by definition.If there are m attributes (in place of the normal Euclidean Function time in 
 calculating this objective function is proportional to m)

Time Complexity of K-means

• Let tdist be the time to calculate the distance between two objects

• Each iteration time complexity: O(Kntdist)

```
K = number of clusters (centroids)

n = number of objects
```

• Bound number of iterations I giving O(IKntdist)

• for m-dimensional vectors: O(IKnm) ----------------> Your Answer

( m large and centroids not sparse )

Space Complexity of K-means

• Store points and centroids

– vector model: O((n + K)m)---------------------->Space Complexity

Answer (score 0):

The space and time complexity of a single iteration of k-means is fairly easy to arrive at (see Rafed's post.) So the real issue is how many iteration are required to reach convergence. This, I believe, is a difficult problem as it is dependent on your data. The k-means algorithm is an example of a bound optimizing algorithm (a.k.a. majorization-minimization algorithm) so [this paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2100646) on the rate of convergence of bound optimizaing algorithms might be relevant to the question of the number of iteration required to converge.